# Binomial distribution variable

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have trouble understanding binomial variable and distribution and what it signifies .

A random variable is a variable whose domain is the sample space and connects each outcome with a number.I also know the conditions for a random variable to binomial variable but I don't know what it signifies .Does it tell the total probability of the sample space satisfied by it........for eg

A dice is thrown 7 times.What is the chance that head comes up four times .

Here ,n=7.   P (success)=1\2  and P (loss)=1/2.
x-number of tines heads comes

P (X=x) -- 7C4 .(1/2)^4.(1/2)^3

What does this P (X=x) signify....the total cases from the sample space showing 4 heads?If it is , is it like the reverse thing because our X used to connect sample space with number and here we are connecting number with a sample space

Comment: Consider reformatting using  MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is the random variable. In this case, it can take on any value from $0$ to $7$. We're concerned with finding the probability that the random variable takes on the value $x$, which in this case, is $4$.

$P(X = x)$ refers to the probability that the random variable $X$ is equal to a particular value, denoted by $x$.

This probability, as you mentioned, can be obtained from the binomial distribution.

$$P(X=x)=P(X=4)={7\choose{4}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^4 \cdot {1\over{2}}^3 \approx.273$$

Note that $$\sum_{x=0}^7 P(X=x)=1$$

We can verify this.

$$P(X=0)={7\choose{0}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^0 \cdot {1\over{2}}^7=0.0078125$$
$$P(X=1)={7\choose{1}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^1 \cdot {1\over{2}}^6=0.0546875$$
$$P(X=2)={7\choose{2}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^2 \cdot {1\over{2}}^5=0.1640625$$
$$P(X=3)={7\choose{3}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^3 \cdot {1\over{2}}^4=0.2734375$$
$$P(X=4)={7\choose{4}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^4 \cdot {1\over{2}}^3=0.2734375$$
$$P(X=5)={7\choose{5}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^5 \cdot {1\over{2}}^2=0.1640625$$
$$P(X=6)={7\choose{6}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^6 \cdot {1\over{2}}^1=0.0546875$$
$$P(X=7)={7\choose{7}}\cdot {1\over{2}}^7 \cdot {1\over{2}}^0=0.0078125$$

These do indeed sum to $1$.

Consider a more simple example where we flip a coin twice, and let $X$ denote the number of heads we obtain. We can either get $HH$, $HT$, $TH$, or $TT$. Then $X$ can take on the values $0$, $1$, or $2$, with probabilities $.25$, $.5$, and $.25$, respectively. We let $X$ be arbitrary and let $x$ be the specified value.

Comment: so will it denote the probability of all those associated with that number

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: but wasn't random variable role was to associate the sample space with a number then why are we doing the reverse here?

Comment: If you want to think in terms of sample space, then $P(X=x)$ is all the ways you can flip $7$ coins and obtain $4$ heads divided by all the ways to flip $7$ coins. I'm a little confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: For eg-P(X=4) will be number of ways probability of (hhhhttt) in any order  ie it tells us the number of ways such probability can come but isn't probability diiferent from number of ways

Comment: Yes, probability is different from the number of ways. A probability is always a value between $0$ and $1$. The probability of an event happening is number of possibilities in the event space / number of possibilities in the sample space

Comment: so in this question what is it asking - probability of 4 heads or number of ways of 4 heads and how do i find out the correct one

Comment: I think this is my main doubt

Comment: It's asking for the probability of getting 4 heads.

Comment: but doesn't this give us the number of ways as you said

Comment: When you see P(something) it's always looking for a probability. To $calculate$ the probability, it is often good to find the number of ways in which said event can occur.

Comment: but will those two be same everytime

Comment: Are you asking if the probability will always equal the number of favorable outcomes over the number of possible outcomes?

Comment: Not that.For eg in this example we are to find probability of 4 heads .so by using the binomial distribution ,we found the number of ways it happens ie-hhhhttt,hththth,ttthhhhh and so on.So if P(X=x=4) is it the sum of probability of the cases i have wriiten above or is the number of times it comes which would be greater than 1

Comment: It's not the number of times it comes. If we write down all $2^7$ ways to arrange 7 heads and tails. Then it's the number of ways in which exactly $4$ heads occur dividing by $2^7$ which will be less than 1 since it's a subset of the $2^7$ possibilities.

Comment: so it's the probability of all those which satisfy this condition ie for this example ttthhhhh and so on....

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: probably their sum ...i get it.thnx for the help